# Can I use HTML4 and Javascript for a mobile version of my site?

Tags: javascript, mobile, smartphone

I want to create a mobile version to http://thenamestork.com. After reading a few posts as well as the official google blog, I understand that a valid mobile site, that will get indexed in google mobile search, is made with different markup languages than html4. I also understand there's a problem with using JS, and my site is JS based (works more like an app than a content-website).

My focus is on smartphones, that CAN handle my site anyway - I thought all I'll need to do is changing the css layout - but there is no point if it won't get indexed by google.

So what's the best way to convert a html4 javacsript site into a valid, search engine friendly mobile version?

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, you're basically asking these two questions: "can I use HTML4/JS for mobile?" and "how can I convert HTML4/JS into search engine friendly markup?". Is that correct? If so: has your question been answered?

Comment: @PPvg The second question is what I'm asking - "what's the best way to convert a html4 javacsript site into a valid, search engine friendly mobile version?". It has not yet been answered - not specifically for google search for mobile.

Comment: Well, to be quite honest: I don't think you need to do anything. Google will happily index any HTML4 site, even if its markup is slightly iffy (i.e. not completely valid). You see -- it's in any search engine's best interest to index anything it possibly can. If your site is not showing up on search engines at all, I suggest you [submit your site to Google](http://www.google.com/submit_content.html) to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google is actually quite forgiving and will index most sites that use something that looks a bit like HTML, even if it's nog 100% valid. Just to be on the safe side, though, you could try [validating your HTML](http://validator.w3.org/).

On the other hand, if you load content asynchronously (i.e. through AJAX), Google might not index it. Search engines generally only index the HTML that's sent to the browser when the page is loaded, without running any JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly use html and javascript for a mobile site for smart phones. Browsers on smart phones are mostly the same as the ones you find on a desktop (with some added features).

[jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) is a good place to start. I have used it for a few sites I've worked on.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, you might also want to check a little of CSS3 and Html5 since mobile devices are mostly compatible with!